# Set random <IMG> inside a div to have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a stack of images, which some JS code fades between the images.

The active image, has an "active" class.

How can I set a random image to have the class so that it never starts from the same place on page loading?

```
<div id="quote">
    <img class="active" src="http://dicktyler.com/dev/images/quote1.png" />
    <img src="http://dicktyler.com/dev/images/quote2.png" />
    <img src="http://dicktyler.com/dev/images/quote3.png" />
    <img src="http://dicktyler.com/dev/images/quote4.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var items = $('#quote img');
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
items.eq(random).addClass('active');
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wBFFf/)**

This will generate a number between `0` and the img `length`, which would be `4` in this case. Then we can use `eq()` to select the image with our randomly generated number.

Comment: We have basically the same answer! Damn airpot wifi & captcha made me post after you :[

Comment: :) Yeah there's basically just 1 simple solution, it could be written a few ways.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to get all the `img`'s in a jQuery object. Next use `eq` to select a specific one from the list. For the value of the `eq` use `Math.random() * $imgs.length` this will give you a number between 0 & however many images there are exclusivly.

```
var $imgs = $('#quote img');

$imgs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $imgs.length)).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

What i would do:

first count the images

```
total_images = $('#quote img').length;
```

then generate a random number between 0 and the total

```
random_num = Math.random() * (total_images - 0) + 0;
```

Then assign the active class to that by selecting it as a child of #quote

```
$('#quote img:nth-child(random_num)').addClass('active');
```

make it a function:

```
function set_random_img(div){
    total_images = $('#'+div+' img').length;
    random_num = Math.random() * (total_images - 0) + 0;
    $('#'+div+' img:nth-child(random_num)').addClass('active');
}
```

and call it:

```
set_random_img('your_div_id');
```